# How to parse the Redis RESP bulk string using nom?

Tags: rust, nom

I need use nom to parse a [RESP](https://redis.io/topics/protocol)  request/reply. When I come to bulk-string, such as

```
"$6\r\nfoobar\r\n"
```

or

```
$-1\r\n
```

First, I write functions to extract the **len** from the data.

```
named!(signed_digits<&str, (Option<&str>, &str)>,
   pair!(
      opt!(alt!(tag!("+") | tag!("-"))),
      nom::digit
   )
);

named!(signed_integer<&str, i64>,
   map_res!(recognize!(signed_digits), FromStr::from_str)
);

named!(get_len_in_bulk_string<&str, i64>,
   do_parse!(
      tag!("$") >>
      len: signed_integer >>
      tag!("\r\n") >>
      (len)
   )
);
```

Then I get the raw string according to the **len**:

```
named!(parse_bulk_string<&str, Record>,
  map_res!(gen_len_in_bulk_string, |n|{
    if n < 0 {
        Record::BulkString(None)
    } else {
        Record::BulkString(Some(take!(n)))
    }
  })
);
```

But I get a compile error:

```
Record::BulkString(Some(take!(n)))
                             ^ missing tokens in macro arguments
```

How can I get the raw string according the **len** which is extracted from the text before? It seems like I cannot use `take!` in my own closure.

Comment: Why not just use an existing Redis crate?

Comment: just for learn how to write a parser using nom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macros like `take!` need an "implicit" argument in the first position: the string to be parsed. Usually you don't see it, because it is passed implicitly when it's nested inside another nom macro.

However, here, you're "calling" it directly, so it needs this argument explicitly.

Instead you could do something like this:

```
named!(get_bulk_string<&str, &str>,
   do_parse!(
      tag!("$") >>
      len: signed_integer >>
      string: take!(len) >>
      tag!("\r\n") >>
      (string)
   )
);
```

Of course, this ignores the `-1` case, which you can handle with a switch:

```
named!(get_bulk_string<&str, Option<&str>>,
   do_parse!(
      tag!("$") >>
      string: switch!(signed_integer,
        -1 => map!(take!(0), |_| None) |
        _ => map!(take!(42), |s| Some(s))
      ) >>
      tag!("\r\n") >>
      (string)
   )
);
```